# get Facebook friends using same app in Ruby on Rails

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I have authenticated the user via Facebook on my ruby on rails website. I have the access token. 
The website/app is registered on Facebook.
My next step is to show friends of the user, who logged into the app via Facebook , who use the same app.
Basically: if I am a user A on an app and I log into the app via Facebook , I should be able to see all my friends who use the app.

I think I can use the: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=....../api/
But that returns friends in this form, I don't don't understand how to use this data to compare the IDs in my website database and then show those who use this app.
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am getting this list on graph API but not on my application. How did you got it?

Answer (score 0):

You should record the Facebook IDs along-side the internal IDs that your site uses, and then use the overlapping of the sets.

You add a column to db to store the facebook id, say, fb_id, and then do

```
ids = res['data'].map { |obj| obj['id'] }
User.where(:fb_id => ids)
```

as far as I remember, ActiveRecord will use "IN (..)" for a column which was passed as array.

Comment: Ye, I understand the logic. But its the programming part thats giving me problems.
1) How do I store this data in any variable?
2) How do I compare?

Comment: Hi Roman,
Thanks for the answer.
This is great, just moving a step before.
I copy pasted the link to find that. But on the code,
do I write:
res['data'] =  https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=....../api/ 
When I do that, it gives me undefined local variable or method `res' for #<#<Class:0x007ffd1b20b4d8>:0x007ffd1b20f970>

I am sorry I am being a bother, very new to ruby on rails.

You have no idea how much this will help.

Comment: "res" is the data structure that you posted in your post

Comment: Use a koala gem: friends =Koala::Facebook::API.new(token).get_connections('me', 'friends')

Comment: Oh alright. I had copy pasted that from the browser when I had that link on domain space.

I tried:
<% friends = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?session[:omniauth]credentials.token/api/' %>
   <% ids = res[friends.data].map { |obj| obj['id'] }
    User.where(:fid => ids)
   %>
still gives me undefined local variable or method `res' for #<#<Class:0x007ffd19453558>:0x007ffd18aacba8>

Sorry again for the basic questions

Comment: Cool did that. Now all the friends are in friends variable.
But ids = friends.map { |obj| obj['id'] }
gives undefined method `map' for "friends":String

Comment: Hey Ankit, could you please help me to get these steps to get friend list of fb friends in my application.